# How to upload an image using mass assignment in laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to use mass assignment. Yet I faced a little problem with uploading an image when attempting such method. 
I added fillable property in **News.php** Model.

```
 protected $fillable = ['title','content','image','status'];
```

My attempt using mass assignment

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //Handle File upload
        if($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/news_images',$fileNameToStore);
        }else
        {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }


           News::create(request(['title','content','image','status']));



       return Redirect('/news');
    }
```

the **error I'm getting**

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'image' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `news` (`title`, `content`, `status`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Hello there !, what are you trying
>   to do ?, 0, 2019-07-13 08:45:46, 2019-07-13 08:45:46)) Previous
>   exceptions SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'image' doesn't
>   have a default value (HY000)

if there is another and easier way to upload an image using mass assignment. Please recommend.

Comment: That error is because you have an image column in your DB but your not putting a value through it. You should store image as the file name.

Comment: I tried News::create(request(['title','content',$fileNameToStore,'status'])); 
but not working

Comment: Because $fileNameToStore isn't a request variable. You should store all the variables you will in in the create method before calling it or it could get a wee bit messy

Comment: I tried storing all variables but no image stored
News::create(request(['title','content','image',
            $filenameWithExt,$filename,$extension,$fileNameToStore,$path ,'status']));
  but when checked the news table in the database >>it has stored this path C:\xampp\tmp\php955F.tmp instead of /storage/news_images/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is an imperfect answer, since it does not use mass-assignment for the image.

```
$news = new News(request(['title', 'content', 'status']));
$news->image = $fileNameToStore;
$news->save();
```

To fully use mass-assignment to set the new image path from the request, you would have to modify the FileBag of the request to somehow contain a 'fake' file that has the new path. This is probably not a good practice, and unless absolutely necessary I would just use the way shown in the snippet above.